# How to scroll the text horizontally and vertically? Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I have UILabel view, i want to move text horizontally RIGHT to LEFT with a fixed duration.I am a newbe plz help! Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean like a ticker label thing?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work fine:

```
CGPoint center = scrollLabel.center;
[UILabel beginAnimations:@"scroll" context:nil];
[UILabel setAnimationDuration:5.0]; // the time the animation should take
center.x -= 500; // whatever distance you'd like
[UILabel commitAnimations];
```

Comment: hey thanks i amnot able to understand wat @"scroll" is.. is that da text to be scrolled .??

Comment: @"scroll" is just the name you'd like to give the animation. You could have called it "fade" or "kowabunga" but neither would make much sense. ;)